# I'm not getting distinct ID's for nested resources in REST api

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

I am writing a REST api of ContactManager, which consists of ContactGroup and Contact entity. The Contact entity is nested in ContactGroup. I want to generate Id of contacts within each ContactGroup starting with 1 and increases sequentially and is independent of other Contact group's contacts.

But, In my code the Id generation of each new contact created in a particular ContactGroup is dependent on the Id of last contact created in other ContactGroup.

For example, If there is two ContactGroup with contactGroupId: 1,2. And I have created 2 contacts in ContactGroupId: 1 with contactId: 1 & 2. Then while creating new contact in ContactGroupId: 2, the contactId generated is 3 but it should be generated as 1.

I am adding the both entities:

ContactGroup.java

```
 @Entity
    public class ContactGroup {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long groupId;
    
        private String name;
    
        private String description;
    
        @OneToMany(targetEntity = Contact.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JsonIgnore
        private List<Contact> contacts;
    
        private Integer numberOfContacts;
    
        public ContactGroup() {
        }
    
        public ContactGroup(String name, String description) {
            this.name = name;
            this.description = description;
        }
    
        //getters & setters
    }
```

Contact.java

```
@Entity
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long contactId;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    private Long phoneNumber;

    private String address;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ContactGroup.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private ContactGroup contactGroup;

    public Contact() {
    }

    public Contact(String name, String email, Long phoneNumber, String address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.address = address;
    }
    // getters & setters
}
```

Kindly, help me out in solving this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Contact.contactId` is a primary key, it must be unique for all contacts. You cannot have contacts with the same id in different contact groups.
You could achieve your goal by using a composite id (contactId, contactGroup) and custom generator for the `contactId`, but I'm not sure it's a good idea.